# How to get all levels data using single SQL query for bill of material

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a lot of bill of material Items and it contains their raw material and semi-finished goods. The semi-finished goods have their own bill of material with raw material and further semi-finished goods and so on.

I want to create a SQL query by which I want to get the details of the bill of material up to the last level. I will put a WHERE clause for the parent bill of material and should get the details up to the last level. It is not limited to 7 levels, some items may even goto 10 or 15 levels.

Below is an example of the hierarchy for example Item 'A'.

[image: Explanation of Bill of Material for Item 'A']

Below is the structure of the table and data in it.

[image: Structure of the table and example data for Item 'A']

Comment: This is a trivial application of hierarchical (`connect by`) queries. But the output is not exactly in the format you show. In fact, the format you show is inconsistent with itself. A uses raw materials B, C, F. In the first three rows, you only show A once. But later in the table, F uses raw materials K and L, and you show F in **both** rows. If that is the **exact** format you want, you will need to explain it better.

Comment: Also, you posted an image for input data (for testing). The only thing worse than posting an image is to not post input data at all. Better: a WITH clause, or CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements to create the data. Worse (but still better than posting an image): post the same table but in plain text formatting. A WITH clause is easiest: `with test_data (bom_code, rm_code, qty) as (select 'A', 'B', 1 from dual union all select 'A', 'C', 2 from dual union all .......`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hierarchical query and filter to only get the leaf nodes.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( bom_code, rm_code, qty ) AS
  SELECT 'A', 'B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'C', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'D', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'E', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'F', 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 'G', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 'H', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 'I', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 'J', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F', 'K', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F', 'L', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'G', 'Z', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'G', 'AA', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I', 'M', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I', 'N', 9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I', 'O', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N', 'P', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N', 'Q', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N', 'R', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N', 'S', 9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S', 'T', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S', 'U', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'T', 'V', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'T', 'W', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U', 'X', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'U', 'Y', 8 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( BOM_CODE, '-' ) || '-' || RM_CODE AS path,
       LEVEL
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH bom_code = 'A'
CONNECT BY PRIOR rm_code = bom_code;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> BOM_CODE | RM_CODE | QTY | PATH           | LEVEL
> :------- | :------ | --: | :------------- | ----:
> A        | B       |   1 | -A-B           |     1
> A        | C       |   2 | -A-C           |     1
> G        | AA      |   3 | -A-D-G-AA      |     3
> G        | Z       |   1 | -A-D-G-Z       |     3
> D        | H       |   1 | -A-D-H         |     2
> I        | M       |   4 | -A-D-I-M       |     3
> N        | P       |   6 | -A-D-I-N-P     |     4
> N        | Q       |  12 | -A-D-I-N-Q     |     4
> N        | R       |   4 | -A-D-I-N-R     |     4
> T        | V       |   1 | -A-D-I-N-S-T-V |     6
> T        | W       |   3 | -A-D-I-N-S-T-W |     6
> U        | X       |   5 | -A-D-I-N-S-U-X |     6
> U        | Y       |   8 | -A-D-I-N-S-U-Y |     6
> I        | O       |   7 | -A-D-I-O       |     3
> D        | J       |   1 | -A-D-J         |     2
> A        | E       |   3 | -A-E           |     1
> F        | K       |   1 | -A-F-K         |     2
> F        | L       |   1 | -A-F-L         |     2
> ```

**Query 2**:

If you want the total quantity along the path then use a correlated sub-query to traverse the hierarchy in the reverse direction:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( BOM_CODE, '-' ) || '-' || RM_CODE AS path,
       LEVEL,
       ( SELECT SUM( qty )
         FROM   table_name s
         START WITH t.rm_code = s.rm_code
         CONNECT BY PRIOR bom_code = rm_code ) AS total_qty
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH bom_code = 'A'
CONNECT BY PRIOR rm_code = bom_code;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> BOM_CODE | RM_CODE | QTY | PATH           | LEVEL | TOTAL_QTY
> :------- | :------ | --: | :------------- | ----: | --------:
> A        | B       |   1 | -A-B           |     1 |         1
> A        | C       |   2 | -A-C           |     1 |         2
> G        | AA      |   3 | -A-D-G-AA      |     3 |        10
> G        | Z       |   1 | -A-D-G-Z       |     3 |         8
> D        | H       |   1 | -A-D-H         |     2 |         6
> I        | M       |   4 | -A-D-I-M       |     3 |        10
> N        | P       |   6 | -A-D-I-N-P     |     4 |        21
> N        | Q       |  12 | -A-D-I-N-Q     |     4 |        27
> N        | R       |   4 | -A-D-I-N-R     |     4 |        19
> T        | V       |   1 | -A-D-I-N-S-T-V |     6 |        28
> T        | W       |   3 | -A-D-I-N-S-T-W |     6 |        30
> U        | X       |   5 | -A-D-I-N-S-U-X |     6 |        31
> U        | Y       |   8 | -A-D-I-N-S-U-Y |     6 |        34
> I        | O       |   7 | -A-D-I-O       |     3 |        13
> D        | J       |   1 | -A-D-J         |     2 |         6
> A        | E       |   3 | -A-E           |     1 |         3
> F        | K       |   1 | -A-F-K         |     2 |         9
> F        | L       |   1 | -A-F-L         |     2 |         9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c3fefebfdd61f7bba2173f77bca97ba6)*

Comment: There may be a need for an ORDER BY clause too (depending on the exact format required). For example, it seems that the OP always want leaf nodes shown first, and only then semi-finished parts under the same parent node.

Comment: @mathguy The OP probably would want an `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` clause rather than using `ORDER BY` but there is no mention of how to order in the question so it appears to be beyond the scope of an answer.

Comment: `order siblings by` won't work if you must order siblings by `connect_by_isleaf`. The ordering may be quite messy. As to scope: your query already doesn't produce the output in the format requested by the OP. More meaningfully, though, the "scope" is not defined yet (clearly the OP has not posted a correct and complete problem statement, so we don't know what the scope is). In solving a problem, one important step is the back-and-forth with the party that posed the problem, to get a clear and complete problem statement. This hasn't occurred yet in this case.