# How to build data using a sub query in loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a list of many bill of materials (BOM) which are available in a table. Now, each BOM has it's own list of items and sub-BOMs called semi-finished items. Recently I got help here on how to build the path of each BOM which is working perfectly fine. The drawback of the query is that it can only support one item at a time by use of a parameter. If the parameter for the item code is removed, the data retrieved is totally wrong.

I need to develop the query so that first of all, it generates a master list of all BOMs and then goes to the first record and generates its full path (details), then loops for the second master BOM and generates it's full path and unions all the records with the previous list of items and so on until it reaches the last master record of BOM.

At the last, I have a correct and proper list of the BOMs with their path.

The below query I tried using Cursor but it requires `INTO`

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1
   IS
        SELECT   BOM_ITEM_CODE BIC
          FROM   BOM_MASTER
         WHERE   BOM_FRZ_FLAG = 2
      GROUP BY   BOM_ITEM_CODE;
BEGIN
   FOR qry IN c1
   LOOP
          -- Start - The below query generates a complete path of any supplied Bill of Material Code
          SELECT   t.BI_ITEM_CODE,
                   BI_BOM_CODE,
                   BI_UOM_CODE,
                   BI_QTY,
                   BI_QTY_LS,
                   BI_QTY_BU,
                   SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (BI_BOM_CODE, '>') || '->' || BI_ITEM_CODE
                      AS PATH,
                   LEVEL,
                   CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE LOOPING_ITEM
            FROM   BOM_ITEM_DETAIL t
      START WITH   BI_BOM_CODE = qry.BIC --This paramter is where the Master Bill of Material Code is supplied.
      CONNECT BY   NOCYCLE PRIOR BI_ITEM_CODE =
                              (SELECT   BOM_ITEM_CODE
                                 FROM   BOM_MASTER
                                WHERE   BOM_CODE = BI_BOM_CODE
                                        AND BOM_FRZ_FLAG = 2);
   -- End of Query which generates the complete path of any supplied Bill of Material Code
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I also tried using WITH but it doesn't give the correct data. It tries to list out all the records wherein the Master BOM code is used at all levels.

```
SELECT   *
    FROM   (WITH qry AS (  SELECT   BOM_ITEM_CODE BIC
                             FROM   BOM_MASTER
                            WHERE   BOM_FRZ_FLAG_NUM = 2
                         GROUP BY   BOM_ITEM_CODE
                         ORDER BY   BOM_ITEM_CODE)
                SELECT   t.BI_ITEM_CODE,
                         BI_BOM_CODE,
                         BI_UOM_CODE,
                         BI_QTY,
                         BI_QTY_LS,
                         BI_QTY_BU,
                            SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (BI_BOM_CODE, '>')
                         || '->'
                         || BI_ITEM_CODE
                            AS PATH,
                         LEVEL
                  FROM   BOM_ITEM_DETAIL t, qry
                 WHERE   BI_BOM_CODE = qry.BIC
            START WITH   BI_BOM_CODE = qry.BIC
            CONNECT BY   NOCYCLE PRIOR BI_ITEM_CODE =
                                    (SELECT   BOM_ITEM_CODE
                                       FROM   BOM_MASTER
                                      WHERE   BOM_CODE = BI_BOM_CODE
                                              AND BOM_FRZ_FLAG_NUM = 2))
ORDER BY PATH
```

My previous question was not well received because I forgot to mention the sample queries which I tried.

My previous question & working sample query/data in accepted answer:

[How to get all levels data using single SQL query for bill of material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557968/how-to-get-all-levels-data-using-single-sql-query-for-bill-of-material)

Comment: What actually is the question ?

Comment: I want to loop through a list of items and build data..

Comment: OK, then let's start from defining a query which `generates a master list of all BOM`. Please explain how this list would be generated (just show the query) - It's hard to reverse engeenier this looking at your question. Once we will have this query, then it will be easy to use CROSS APPLY join to build the final solution.

Comment: Thanks. This query will generate a master list of all BOM.  `SELECT   BOM_ITEM_CODE BIC
          FROM   BOM_MASTER
         WHERE   BOM_FRZ_FLAG = 2
      GROUP BY   BOM_ITEM_CODE;`. I want to loop this query and for each record, generate its details.

Comment: This query will generate the details of any given BOM. `SELECT   
             SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (BI_BOM_CODE, '>') || '->' || BI_ITEM_CODE
                AS PATH,
             LEVEL
      FROM   BOM_ITEM_DETAIL  t
START WITH   BI_BOM_CODE = 'XYZ'
CONNECT BY   NOCYCLE PRIOR BI_ITEM_CODE =
                        (SELECT   BOM_ITEM_CODE
                           FROM   OM_BOM
                          WHERE   BOM_CODE = BI_BOM_CODE
                                  AND BOM_FRZ_FLAG_NUM = 2)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the situation where start with condition lies in the master table and children are in the child table.

I have demonstrated a small code to visualize and resolve the same issue.

```
CREATE TABLE M (ID NUMBER);
INSERT INTO M VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO M VALUES(10);
commit;
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID NUMBER, PARENT_ID NUMBER);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1,NULL);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (3,1);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (4,2);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (5,2);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (10,NULL);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (12,10);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (7,10);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (11,10);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (6,1);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (13,1);
COMMIT;
```

Query to fetch the desired result:

```
SELECT T1.ID, M.ID,
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH ( T1.id, '>') AS PATH, LEVEL
FROM
T1 LEFT JOIN M -- did left join on master table
ON (T1.ID = M.ID)
CONNECT BY PRIOR T1.ID =  T1.PARENT_ID
START WITH M.ID IS NOT NULL -- start with a condition (IMP)
```

Output:

[image]

Cheers!!